# Passing iterator as argument in Nim fails "attempting to call undeclared routine"

Tags: iterator, nim-lang

I'm trying to learn Nim by writing a certain bioinformatics tool that I already implemented in other languages.

I have the following version that compiles and runs apparently correctly:

```nimrod
from strutils import join
from sequtils import zip

type
  Nucleotides = distinct string
  Qualities = distinct string
  #Nucleotides = string
  #Qualities = string
  Fastq = tuple
    name: string
    nucls: Nucleotides
    quals: Qualities

# proc `==` (ns, ms: Nucleotides): bool =
#   string(ns) == string(ms)
# https://nim-by-example.github.io/types/distinct/
proc `==` (ns, ms: Nucleotides): bool {.borrow.}

proc makeFastq(name, nucls, quals: string): Fastq =
  result = (name: name, nucls: nucls.Nucleotides, quals: quals.Qualities)

proc bestQuals(quals1, quals2: string): string =
  let N = min(quals1.len, quals2.len)
  result = newStringOfCap(N)
  for pair in zip(quals1, quals2):
    result.add(chr(max(ord(pair.a), ord(pair.b))))

proc bestQuals(quals1, quals2: Qualities): Qualities =
  result = bestQuals(string(quals1), string(quals2)).Qualities

proc fuseFastq(rec1, rec2: Fastq): Fastq =
  result = (name: rec1.name, nucls: rec1.nucls, quals: bestQuals(rec1.quals, rec2.quals))

proc `$` (record: Fastq): string =
  result = join([
    record.name,
    string(record.nucls),
    "+",
    string(record.quals)], "\n")

iterator parseFastqs(input: File): Fastq =
  var
    nameLine: string
    nucLine: string
    quaLine: string
  while not input.endOfFile:
    nameLine = input.readLine()
    nucLine = input.readLine()
    discard input.readLine()
    quaLine = input.readLine()
    yield makeFastq(nameLine, nucLine, quaLine)

proc deduplicate() =
  var
    record: Fastq
  record = (name: "", nucls: "".Nucleotides, quals: "".Qualities)
  for fastq in parseFastqs(stdin):
    if record.nucls != fastq.nucls:
      if record.name != "":
        echo $record
      record = fastq
    else:
      record = fuseFastq(record, fastq)
      continue
  if record.name != "":
    echo $record

when isMainModule:
  deduplicate()
```

Now, I would like to have `deduplicate` take as argument the "thing" (currently an iterator) that generates `Fastq` tuples. It would indeed seem much cleaner to have the `when isMainModule` part deal with reading from stdin or possibly something else in the future (a file passed as command-line argument, for instance):

```nimrod
proc deduplicate(inputFqs: <some relevant type>) =
  var
    record: Fastq
  record = (name: "", nucls: "".Nucleotides, quals: "".Qualities)
  for fastq in inputFqs:
    if record.nucls != fastq.nucls:
      if record.name != "":
        echo $record
      record = fastq
    else:
      record = fuseFastq(record, fastq)
      continue
  if record.name != "":
    echo $record

when isMainModule:
  let inputFqs = parseFastqs(stdin)
  deduplicate(inputFqs)
```

**Is there a simple and efficient way to do this?**

I naïvely tried the following:

```nimrod
proc deduplicate(inputFqs: iterator) =
  var
    record: Fastq
  record = (name: "", nucls: "".Nucleotides, quals: "".Qualities)
  for fastq in inputFqs:
    if record.nucls != fastq.nucls:
      if record.name != "":
        echo $record
      record = fastq
    else:
      record = fuseFastq(record, fastq)
      continue
  if record.name != "":
    echo $record

when isMainModule:
  let inputFqs = parseFastqs(stdin)
  deduplicate(inputFqs)
```

And this results in the following compilation error: `Error: attempting to call undeclared routine: 'parseFastqs'`.

I searched and understood from the [manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#iterators-and-the-for-statement-first-class-iterators) that I should make my iterator a closure iterator. So I started simply by just using the `{.closure.}` pragma:

```nimrod
iterator parseFastqs(input: File): Fastq {.closure.} =
```

But I kept having the same error.

So I tried mimicking more closely the example given in the manual:

```nimrod
iterator parseFastqs(input: File): Fastq {.closure.} =
  var
    nameLine: string
    nucLine: string
    quaLine: string
  while not input.endOfFile:
    nameLine = input.readLine()
    nucLine = input.readLine()
    discard input.readLine()
    quaLine = input.readLine()
    yield makeFastq(nameLine, nucLine, quaLine)

proc deduplicate(inputFqs: iterator(): Fastq {.closure.}) =
  var
    record: Fastq
  record = (name: "", nucls: "".Nucleotides, quals: "".Qualities)
  for fastq in inputFqs:
    if record.nucls != fastq.nucls:
      if record.name != "":
        echo $record
      record = fastq
    else:
      record = fuseFastq(record, fastq)
      continue
  if record.name != "":
    echo $record

deduplicate(parseFastqs(stdin))
```

This resulted in a type error:

```
Error: type mismatch: got (iterator (): Fastq{.closure.})
but expected one of: 
iterator items[T](a: set[T]): T
iterator items(a: cstring): char
iterator items[T](a: openArray[T]): T
iterator items[IX, T](a: array[IX, T]): T
iterator items(a: string): char
iterator items[T](a: seq[T]): T
iterator items(E: typedesc[enum]): E:type
iterator items[T](s: HSlice[T, T]): T

expression: items(inputFqs)
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

#### Edit: Solving the type issue

It seems that the type mismatch can be solved by changing `for fastq in inputFqs:` to `for fastq in inputFqs():`. The situation is back to `Error: attempting to call undeclared routine: 'parseFastqs'`.

Some tinkering with the example from the manual reveals that the type of the iterator parameter does not need to have the parentheses. The following compiles and runs correctly:

```nimrod
iterator count0(): int {.closure.} =
  yield 0

iterator count2(): int {.closure.} =
  var x = 1
  yield x
  inc x
  yield x

proc invoke(iter: iterator) =
  for x in iter(): echo x

invoke(count0)
invoke(count2)
```

Now I would be interested in **the meaning of the parentheses** in the original example:

```nimrod
proc invoke(iter: iterator(): int {.closure.}) =
```

Answer (score 2):

You must *loop over* an `iterator`

```
for item in myIterator():
  echo repr item
```

or you could transform it into a sequence

```
import sequtils
echo toSeq(myIterator())
```